# New Summoners Rift Icons

Tags: league-of-legends

**[SR Open Beta begins with Team Builder and Bot](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/sr-open-beta-begins)**

> You can earn each icon by winning a game on each side of the map.  Win once on red side? Earn the red side icon. Win a game as the blue team? The blue side icon is yours. Win as red and blue both? You’re the new owner of two nifty icons. Do it at the same time somehow? You’ve broken the internet and your prize is the singularity. The icons will be available for the next several weeks.

[image]
[image]

**Will you get them if you win against Bots or must it be in Team Builder?**

Comment: There's no indication that it needs to be won in Team builder, my guess it's either one.

Comment: Tested in Co-op vs Bots, cannot earn the icon. For me.

Answer (score 1):

There's no information regarding that it is required to play on Team Builder.

However some people on [Surrender @ 20](http://www.surrenderat20.net/2014/11/summoners-rift-open-beta.html#more) are claiming that you can receive the icons playing **Co-Op vs Bots.**

So my guess is that **you can** win the icons in both modes.

Any update and I'll update my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just played one Coop (blue side) and one Team Builder.

Coop as the first one, but i haven't received the icon yet, as opposed to red icon from TB wich got right away

Comment: lets wait a little and try not to win blue side witheambuilder :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get these icons anymore because the promotion has [ended](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/sr-summoner-icon-promotion-ending-soon)

And you get [them](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/sr-open-beta-live-all-queues) by winning on the blue and red side of the Summoners Rift Beta in the normal queue or team builder queue.

Comment: this is true. but not an answer to this question

Comment: i don't believe you could have gotten them with the Coop vs AI queue as it is not stated in the post, you only could have gotten them by winning normal queue or team builder queue and when played on the summoners rift beta,